# How to pass command line argument to Xcode based on build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line-arguments

I would like to add the `-FIRDebugEnabled` argument to enable the debug view on the Firebase console but only when it is a debug or staging build.

I have tried adding `CommandLine.arguments.append("-FIRDebugEnabled")`  in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but this does not seem to work, so I think I need to add it during a Build phase or a pre-action in the release scheme. But I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just add it as a launch argument in your scheme?

Comment: @andlin yes that is an option but as I work in an agency we don't want to think about it on every project when making builds.
Thats why I would like a code block or script that handles it for us to reduce human error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, launch arguments added to a scheme are only set when building the app from within Xcode directly to a device or the simulator. If you wish to set FIRDebugEnabled in other cases (so that it's also set when the user launches the app on the actual device), maybe this will work:

```
var newArguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
newArguments.append("-FIRDebugEnabled")
ProcessInfo.processInfo.setValue(newArguments, forKey: "arguments")
```

Comment: Awesome! That seems to work, just need to wrap it in 
`#if DEBUG || STAGING` and its exactly what I wanted.
Thanks @andlin